# OSMDroid in Android Studio

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, osmdroid

I have imported the OSMDroid full project in Android Studio through POM.xml file.  It was imported but following error occurred

```
2:00:03 AM Error when importing module 'Google wrapper sample application': Cannot find file C:\Users\DevilsDream\.m2\repository\com\google\android\gms\google-play-services\27.0.0\google-play-services-27.0.0.pom
2:00:12 AM Error when importing module '~apklib-com.google.android.gms_google-play-services_27.0.0': Cannot find file C:\Users\DevilsDream\.m2\repository\com\google\android\gms\google-play-services\27.0.0\google-play-services-27.0.0.apklib
2:00:12 AM Error when importing module '~apklib-com.google.android.gms_google-play-services_27.0.0': Cannot find sdk info for artifact com.google.android.gms:google-play-services:27.0.0
2:00:12 AM Error when importing module '~apklib-com.google.android.gms_google-play-services_27.0.0': Cannot find resolved info for artifact com.google.android.gms:google-play-services:27.0.0
```

What should I do to work with OSMDroid in Android Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

osmdroid uses maven for a build system (for time being). The maven android plugin doesn't import correctly with android studio. You may have better luck with intellj. You shouldn't need to import the project into android studio. You really only need to include the dependencies of osmdroid in your project.

Osmdroid does have gradle build files for the example application to ease development.

per https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-add-the-osmdroid-library-via-Gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:4.4'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.6.1'
}
```

You'll also want to consult the wiki on how to use Osmdroid here: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-use-the-osmdroid-library

Comment: I am newbie in Android Development. Is there any Step by step tutorial? I tried whole day but there are lot of errors to build project.

Comment: Are you trying to "use" osmdroid or build osmdroid?

Comment: follow this, https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-use-the-osmdroid-library example gradle script is here https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/OpenStreetMapViewer/build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

I am using osmdroid v.4.2:

```
dependencies {
compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:4.2'
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.6.1'
}
```